# Need SELECT WHERE COUNT = INT in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have the following table that records when a particular room in a hotel (designated by a three character code [dlx, sup, jac, etc..]) is sold out on a particular `DATETIME`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RoomSoldOut](
    [SoldOutID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RoomType] [nchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [SoldOutDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_RoomSoldOut5] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

I need to find out when a particular date is sold out in the entire hotel. There are 8 room types and if all 8 are sold out then the hotel is booked solid for that night.

the LINQ statement to count the roomtypes sold for a given night works like this.

```
var solds = from r in RoomSoldOuts
   group r by r.SoldOutDate into s   
   select new
   {
      Date = s.Key,  
      RoomTypeSoldOut = s.Count() 
   };
```

from this LINQ statement I can get a list of all the sold out `DATETIME`'s with a COUNT of the number of rooms that are sold out.

I need to filter this list to only those `DATETIME`'s where the `COUNT` = 8, because then the hotel is sold out for that day.

This should be simple but I can not figure out how to do it in LINQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you need to add the following to the query: `where s.Count()==8`

Answer (score 4):

You can also try

```
var solds = (from r in RoomSoldOuts
            group r by r.SoldOutDate into s
            select new
            {
                Date = s.Key,
                RoomTypeSoldOut = s.Count()
            }).Where(x => x.RoomTypeSoldOut == 8);
```

You could then also have shortened it to only select the dates

```
var solds = from r in RoomSoldOuts
            group r by r.SoldOutDate into s
            where s.Count() == 8
            select s.Key;
```

Comment: I like the extension method but is there any benefit over adding the simple 'where s.Count() == 8' from @Konamiman ? Seems more complex than needed?

Comment: That will make an LINQ-to-Objects query around the LINQ-to-SQL query, so it will create objects from all records and filter afterwards instead of using HAVING in the SQL query.

Comment: I would assume you are saying that doing the filter SQL SERVER side is better so we don't transport un-needed data back to the client. I would agree!